# Can't implement results output by PAW Code Generator

Tags: jquery, rest, http, post, paw-app

Thanks to anyone for taking the time!

I am new to development so I searched and experimented for over 10 hours (not all at once) before coming here to ask.

I am using **PAW** to create a single (html?) file with only the code needed to execute an HTTP Post request clientside, in a browser, so when the user opens the file in the browser, they see the resulting csv.
(example of PAW output code I am working with is below)

Seemed like it should be simple, the call works in PAW and other HTTP Test Utilities

**I have been trying to use the output text from the Code Generator Extensions for JavaScript and HTTP** .

- **HTTP**:

  - I tried wrapping the results in html tags with different combinations of parts or all of the statement in header and/or body sections
- **JavaScript (jQuery)**

  - I have examined example/template html files with javascripts, and have attempted to replicate, using many variations and file extensions (.html, .js)

I hope the solution would be as easy as someone providing me with the code to wrap around the PAW Code Generators output (or a link telling how to do so), so I can save it to a file, load it in a browser, and have it work. (but any assistance is appreciated).

I would use whatever PAW Code Generator output works.

**Thanks for anyone who might take the time to help!!!**

Jim

-

-

---

**Output Results**

From PAW HTTP Code Generator

```
POST /api/adwords/reportdownload/v201409?__rdquery=SELECT%20CampaignId%2C%20ClickType%2C%20Impressions%20FROM%20CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT%20DURING%20THIS_MONTH&__fmt=CSV HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx
developerToken: xxxxxxxxxxx
clientCustomerId: xxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: adwords.google.com
Connection: close
```

From PAW  JavaScript (jQuery) Code Generator:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201409",
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        "__rdquery":"SELECT CampaignId, ClickType, Impressions FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING THIS_MONTH",
        "__fmt":"CSV",
    },
    headers:{
        "clientCustomerId":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Authorization":"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "developerToken":"xxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log("HTTP Request Succeeded: " + jqXHR.status);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("HTTP Request Failed");
    }
});
```